# The proper usage of commas?

Tags: commas, quotes

If I have some quotes like "Never, never, never give up!" can I put a comma after them?

Basically, which one is correct:

1. He said "There is no in between", and I can't agree more!

or

2. He said "There is no in between" and I can't agree more!

Comment: This has nothing to do with quotes. Would you put a comma in "He did X, and I did Y"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take:

*He said, "**There is no in between,**" and I can't agree more!*

This is how usually dialogue is reported.

Comma before "and" as those are independent clauses (different subjects).